# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.exceptions'

Tags: odoo-11

I just installed Odoo11 from source code.

When I run

```
max@max-go:~/Workspace/odoo11$ ./odoo-bin
```

I get the following error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in
<module>
  import odoo File "/home/max/Workspace/odoo11/odoo/__init__.py", line 84, in
  <module>
    from . import modules File "/home/max/Workspace/odoo11/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in
    <module>
      from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry File "/home/max/Workspace/odoo11/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in
      <module>
        import odoo.tools as tools File "/home/max/Workspace/odoo11/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 20, in
        <module>
          from .xml_utils import * File "/home/max/Workspace/odoo11/odoo/tools/xml_utils.py", line 4, in
          <module>
            from odoo.exceptions import UserError ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.exceptions
```

Can anyone please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
import your_model_name
```

to

```
from . import your_model_name
```